# run an executable that was downloaded from blob into stream in c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've downloaded an executable file from my Cloud blob, and now I want to run the file.

here's my relevant piece of code:

```
Stream codeContent = new MemoryStream();
blobClientCode.GetBlockBlobReference(codeUri).DownloadToStream(codeContent);
codeContent.Position = 0;

Process p = new Process();
```

Now I want to run the executable I've downloaded. I guess that I need to use a Process for that, I just don't know how. can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Save the blob content to a local .exe file and then start it as a Process.

Comment: @Rytmis Can you please show me how to do that, in code, please? I'm dealing with a language I don't fully know yet here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do. Pass your blob as the first parameter and the local file path as the second:

```
public static void RunBlob(ICloudBlob blob, string targetFilePath) {
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(targetFilePath)) {
        blob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
    }

    var process = new Process() {StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(targetFilePath)};
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit(); // Optional
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though the workerRole where I put this code stucks in the middle.

Comment: What does that mean? Did you note that if you call WaitForExit, the method will block until the process you started ends? If that's not desired, just comment out the last line.

Comment: the last line is fine, but I get UnauthorizedAccess Exception, even though the uri is ok and has a public access

Comment: Which line does the exception come from, and what does it say exactly?

Comment: And the complete stack trace and error message? Can you paste them to pastebin or somesuch?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28211/discussion-between-rytmis-and-user1067083)